# Do I need commercial development to access sandbox?

Tags: nest-device-access

Hi I have a quick question about developing using the device access. If I want to program my nest Thermostat and have access to the sandbox, do I need to apply for commercial development? Can someone also explain what the sandbox is more thoroughly?

Answer (score 0):

The sandbox is the default environment everyone gets access to once you register for the program through the console. It's intended to be used for personal integrations or evaluating the API. So if you just want to program your personal thermostat, the sandbox is all you need.

Commercial development is for those who wish to integrate Device Access into a commercial app or offering that may involve hundreds or thousands of users with their own Nest devices. You do not need to apply for it to get access to the sandbox.